# Android link to Google Fusion Table

Tags: android, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I want to develop an app on the Android. Which can get the wifi information then insert into the fusion table.
Is there any example code or source code avaliable to show how could I do with it ?

Comment: The google project "fusion-tables-android" is not working.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/sample_code

OR

try App inventor Fusion Tables Control

http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/

Comment: I think the App inventor is already gone.I can not open the webpage for developing.And I have download the sample "fusion-tables-android".It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`FusionTableService`](https://github.com/jedld/GiNote/blob/master/src/com/dayosoft/utils/FusionTableService.java) class in my Android application.

This should be everything you need.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.