# Shp layer to Fusion Table

Tags: android, google-maps, arcgis, shapefile

I need to store a .shp file (vector data file) in Fusion table and then "get" him from the fusion table and use it as a layer/overlay on my MapView in android (using google map Api)

is it possible ? 
a sample of how to do it will be helpful...

Thanks in advance ! Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I use [shpescape.com](http://shpescape.com) to convert a shapefile to Fusion Tables, super useful. Getting it in a MapView is a bit trickier, because there is no "official" way to do it in the SDK. You may find some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9432198/android-link-to-google-fusion-table) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-android/).

Answer (score 0):

The url that Gady P shared works, but here are some alternative options:

You need to get your shapefile into KML format. You can either use the Layer to KML tool in ArcGIS. It can be found in Toolboxes > System Toolboxes > Conversion Tools > From KML > KML to Layer.

You can also use GDAL/ogr2ogr to convert the shapefile to KML. I wrote a tutorial on doing this at the GISCollective website a few months ago...

http://giscollective.org/tutorials/gis-techniques/spatial-data-conversion-using-python/

It should be enough to walk you through how to convert it to KML.

Once you have it converted to KML just go to Google Drive and create your Fusion Table, then upload the KML from your computer.

EDIT: After re-reading my tutorial, it seems I give an example of converting a shapefile to KML, so this should be exactly what you need